# Problems sampling color from image-pixel drawn on off-screen canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, sample

I need to sample the pixel-color from an image, but it seems like I can't get it right. I load the image and draw it to an off-screen canvas, then I try to sample the pixel-color but I always get 0-values.

**My code:**

```
// Create canvas and set context
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 8;
canvas.width = 8;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Setup image
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'img.png';
image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

// Sample a random pixel from the canvas
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
var pixelInfo = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
var rgbaVal = pixelInfo.data;
alert('Image: '+image.src+'\n\nR: '+rgbaVal[0]+'\nG: '+rgbaVal[1]+'\nB: '+rgbaVal[2]+'\nA: '+rgbaVal[3]+'\n\nCoords: '+x+', '+y);
```

I get no errors and if I try to draw the image on an on-screen canvas, the image draws correctly. I can't manage to find the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the image hasnt been loaded and drawn yet. You draw it after the onload is fired, then you should get the RGB value too.

The image.onload function will fire later then your sampling function, so you just sample an empty canvas at the moment.

Comment: But even if I remove the .onload and just draw the image (context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);) to the canvas I still get the same result. Something tells me that I don't really draw the image to the canvas the right way?

Comment: Dont remove the onload, get the pixel colors in the onload instead.

Comment: Well, that work, but only while not running the code localy. Is there any work-around (That doesn't involve setting browser arguments on startup and such)?

Comment: if you have python installed, cd to the directory with your files in it and enter -

python -m SimpleHTTPServer

I had the exact same issue as you a couple of weeks ago, this was the approach I took.

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200", height="200" style="background:red;">Random Canvas</canvas>
<script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    //canvas.width = 200;
    //canvas.width = 200;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Setup image
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "img/image.jpg";

    image.onload = function()
    {

       context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

       var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
       var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
       var pixelInfo = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
       var rgbaVal = pixelInfo.data;

       alert('Image: '+image.src+'\n\nR: '+rgbaVal[0]+'\nG: '+rgbaVal[1]+'\nB: '+rgbaVal[2]+'\nA: '+rgbaVal[3]+'\n\nCoords: '+x+', '+y);

    }

    // Sample a random pixel from the canvas

</script>
```